# Working with PHP Strings + result returning unknown equal sign?

Tags: php, string, strpos

I have a string variable named `$message` as below:

```
        * Time Stamp: 2012-12-03 16:36:04 
        * Speed: 7 km/h 
        * Heading: 356 deg (N) 
        * Event ID: -48 
        * Event Desc: .Arrived at Inbound Receiving 
        * Event Value: -56
        * Event Value Type: 0
```

I then try to extract the event and timestamp values from the variable with the below code:

```
$event = null;
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $message);
foreach($lines as $line) {
  // skip empty lines
  if(strlen($line) == 0) {
    continue;
  }
  $tokens = explode(':', $line);
  // tokens[0] contains the key , e.g. Event Value
  // tokens[1]~[N] contains the value (where N is the number of pieces), e.g. -56
  // stitch token 1 ~ N
  $key = $tokens[0]; 
  unset($tokens[0]);
  $val = implode(': ', $tokens);
  // do your extra logic here, e.g. set $event variable to value
  if(strpos($key, 'Event Desc') > -1) {
    $event = $val;
  }
   if(strpos($key, 'Time Stamp') > -1) {
   $time = $val;
  }
}
```

This works great, only problem is that the returned values are:

```
.Arrived at Arrived at Inbound Receiving =

2012-12-03 16:36:04  =
```

Where does the equal sign come from and how can I remove it along with the trailing spaces?

my expected result would be:

```
.Arrived at Arrived at Inbound Receiving
```

and

```
2012-12-03 16:36:04
```

This is how it appears in the string variable.
Thanks as always.

Comment: Can you add your expected result also

Comment: Regular expressions. This is what they were made for.

Comment: Is this `$message` by chance coming from an email?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. Baba, I have added my expected results to question. @sberry, 100% correct, coming from an email pipe on cpanel and outputs of processing being emailed to me. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer for a possible way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
preg_match_all("/ ([a-z ]+):([a-z0-9:\-. ]+)/i", $string,$match);
$values = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]) ;

echo $values['Time Stamp'] ,PHP_EOL ;
echo $values['Speed'] ,PHP_EOL ;
echo $values['Heading'] ,PHP_EOL ;
echo $values['Event Desc'] ,PHP_EOL ;
// .... etc
```

Output

```
 2012-12-03 16:36:04 
 7 km
 356 deg 
 .Arrived at Inbound Receiving
```

[Online Demo](http://eval.in/4255)

Comment: This is awesome, thanks baba. one last question though, how can I set the value equal to a variable, like `$one=$values['Time Stamp'] ,PHP_EOL ;` obviously this doesn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: and why does `echo $values['Event Desc'] ,PHP_EOL ;` not work but the rest do? Thanks again @Baba

Comment: Genius, thank you. time for me to get reading so I can understand what just happened :-)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are getting `$message` contents from an email.  If that is the case, then try running the contents through [quoted_printable_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) first.

Comment: Thanks sberry. appreciate your time. a little overwhelming, I will need to do my reading. Am I correct with this:`$messagetwo=  return preg_replace('/[^\r\n]{73}[^=\r\n]{2}/', "$0=\r\n", str_replace("%","=",str_replace("%20"," ",rawurlencode($message))));`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you proper key and value.

```
list($key, $value) = explode(':', $line, 2);
$key = trim($key);
$value = trim(quoted_printable_decode($value));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
echo $time;
echo $event;
```

it will display 2012-12-03 16: 36: 04 .Arrived at Inbound Receiving only